# Im trying to creatre a table in MySQL but i keep getting an error. Not sure what the issue is

Tags: mysql

Im using MYSQL 8.In the terminal it says to check syntax. Here is the chart.

create table order(
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
customer_id INTEGER,
subtotal DECimal,
tax DECimal,
total DEC,
purchase_at DATE,
updated_at DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer (id),
);

I was trying to create a table and expecting it to run without error.

Answer (score 1):

`order` is a keyword, so I changed it to `orders`

Removed a trailing comma near the end of the line.

```
create table orders(
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, 
customer_id INTEGER, 
subtotal DECimal, 
tax DECimal, 
total DEC, 
purchase_at DATE, 
updated_at DATE, 
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
REFERENCES customer (id));
```